# ReSharper Display Items still show up after uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.1

After uninstalling ReSharper 6.1 from VS 2010, ReSharper Display Items still show up in the Fonts and Colors settings. How do I remove these? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something's gone wrong with the (un)installer, try these steps:

1. Uninstall all R# versions.
2. Delete any leftover R# files from under `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\JetBrains"`
3. Delete any leftover R# files from under `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Extensions\JetBrains"` (highliy unlikely to be there).
4. For VS11, touch the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged"` file.
5. Run `devenv.com /Setup`.
6. For the Fonts'n'colors problem, try also cleaning up the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\FontAndColors\Cache` Registry key.